# How to control time delay between two sections in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, delay

I'm making an app that consists of two sections. One is a PageView section you can change pages with a Swipe motion. Another shows which page you are in now after you change pages. But there is time delay. When I change pages like page one to page two, the lower section's change with about 0.5-second delay.

To find any causes, I declared index as double(It's redeclared as int now). And I found when I change pages in my first section PageView, the lower section shows decimal change(i.g. not 1 -> 2, but 1.0 -> 1.xxx -> 2). 
I also tried the Switch-case statement. In this statement, default is returns Text('nothing'). And I found when being changed, the lower section shows nothing.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
      var scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal;
      var actionIcon = Icons.swap_vert;
      int index;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        index = 0;
        controller.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            index = controller.page.toInt();
          });
        });
      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('it\'s a drill for page view'),
          ),
          body: _buildBody(),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildBody() {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text('it is $index');
                  },
                )
                ),
              Expanded(
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: _showContent()
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
      );
      }

      Widget _showContent() {
        switch (index) {
          case 0: return Text('One');
          break;
          case 1: return Text('Two');
          break;
          case 2: return Text('Three');
          break;
          case 3: return Text('Four');
          break;
          case 4: return Text('Five');
          break;
          default: return Text('Nothing');
        }
      }
    }
```

I want two-section not to have any delays. Is there any solution?
Please help me. I'm a real beginner. So maybe I beg your pardon. But I never let this question left unattended. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably rounding the value of the current page in the PageController listener is more suitable for you.

Here is the modified listener code:

```
controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    index = controller.page.round();
  });
});
```

Comment: I already tried to do as you say but it didn't work. But I finally solved this problem thanks to another one's solution to my former question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
 Timer(
    Duration(seconds: 3),
        (){ //return YOU CAN PUT YOUR STUFF HERE.});
```

Comment: Hey Dear are you want to doing animation kind delay? OR something else?

Comment: No, actually I don't want any delay. It will be perfect that the lower section changes when I change page in PageView, the upper section.